# Classic ASP - Declaring variables in File_1.asp absent in Include File

Tags: asp-classic, server-side-includes

I have declared a variable and it's value in the head of File_1.asp Before DOCTYPE html

```
<%
dim strCategory
strCategory="My String"
%>
```

Then I have an include file inserted in the body

```
<!--#include file="../_assets/includes/jumbotron.inc"-->
```

In the include file I loop through a recordset to compare the declared variable

```
<%
if objRS("fldCategory")=strCategory then
  strActive="active"
End If
%>
```

But I get an error "Variable is undefined: 'strCategory'". The variable "strCategory" value must be assigned in File_1.asp so how do I use this variable in the "include" file?

Comment: Presumably you're using `Option Explicit`? It could be an issue with `.inc` files being treated as static content. Try renaming the extension to `.asp` and updating your include link.

Comment: Make sure that the declaration of the `strCategory` variable is made at the global scope level, before any Include, any sub of function definition.